# how compare 2 DataFrames and give unigvalue from one df column to the other

Tags: python, pandas

I will need your help please in the following problem I am facing:

I have 2  dataframes (df_big and df_small) with many columns each one.
In the df_small each row have unique combination for the columns ‘a’, ‘b’,’c’, ‘d’,’e’
in the df_big exist  rows have same values with df_small at ‘a’, ‘b’,’c’, ‘d’,’e’
but exist and rows with same ‘a’, ‘b’,’c’, ‘d’ and different value in ‘e’ column.

I would like in df_big the rows with same values with df_small in columns ‘a’, ‘b’,’c’, ‘d’
have only one value in the column ‘e’ . Must be the value from df_small.

```
    while i < len(df_small):
    while j < len(df_big):

        if ((df_big.iat[j,df_big.columns.get_loc('a')]  == df_small.iat[i,df_small.columns.get_loc('a')]) &
                        (df_big.iat[j,df_big.columns.get_loc('b')]  == df_small.iat[i,df_small.columns.get_loc('b')]) &
                        (df_big.iat[j,df_big.columns.get_loc('c')]  == df_small.iat[i,df_small.columns.get_loc('c')]) &

                        (df_big.iat[j,df_big.columns.get_loc('d')]  == df_small.iat[i,df_small.columns.get_loc('d')]) ):

                            df_big.iat[j,df_big.columns.get_loc('e')]  = df_small.iat[i,df_small.columns.get_loc('e')]
        else:
                            pass
    j= j + 1
i = i +1
```

i have many tries and with if and iloc but I did not make it.
could someone help me please!

```
df1    a  b  c  d  e  f  k  m  n
0      4  5  9  0  6  5  5  8  5
1      8  6  6  6  6  1  2  5  3          
2      5  7  1  1  5  2  6  7  2   
3      0  3  1  0  2  6  4  5  3       
4      4  8  5  1  6  7  5  7  9
5      5  6  9  5  6  9  4  5  8
6      2  4  3  9  2  8  1  5  9       


df2  a  b  c  d   e  f  k   m   n
3    0  3  1  0  60  6  40  50  30
6    2  4  3  9  80  8  20  40  20
9    1  9  7  8  40  5  30  20  80
```

the new question is how can update not only 'e' column but  the 'e' and 'k' and 'm' and 'n' column.
and
the row 9 from df2 can added to df1?
thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
np.random.seed(2021)
df_big = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(7, 6)), columns=list('abcdef'))

df_small = df_big[df_big['a'].le(2)].assign(e = lambda x: x['b'] * x['e'] * 10)
print (df_big)
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  4  5  9  0  6  5
1  8  6  6  6  6  1
2  5  7  1  1  5  2
3  0  3  1  0  2  6
4  4  8  5  1  6  7
5  5  6  9  5  6  9
6  2  4  3  9  2  8

print (df_small)
   a  b  c  d   e  f
3  0  3  1  0  60  6
6  2  4  3  9  80  8
```

---

```
df_big = df_big.set_index(['a','b','c','d'])
df_small = df_small.set_index(['a','b','c','d'])['e']

#if possible duplicates per a,b,c,d remove them
#df_small = df_small.drop_duplicates(['a','b','c','d']).set_index(['a','b','c','d'])['e']

df_big.update(df_small)
df_big = df_big.reset_index()
print (df_big)
   a  b  c  d     e  f
0  4  5  9  0   6.0  5
1  8  6  6  6   6.0  1
2  5  7  1  1   5.0  2
3  0  3  1  0  60.0  6
4  4  8  5  1   6.0  7
5  5  6  9  5   6.0  9
6  2  4  3  9  80.0  8
```

Comment: Very good and looks simple solution …..thank you !!!
if can help me an the next step…

I have and one more df_huge >df_big and the problem is :

must replace from df_huge the values from df_big in column ‘e’ but only in the  same number index   (not from set_index ‘a’, ‘b’,’c’, ‘d’)

can you help me?

I have many tries find with google and stackoverflow but I am sure dont ask the right question ,could you suggest me something?

Comment: can be done this for more columns like 'e' : for 'e' ,'k', 'm','n'... from a list of columns or must be repeat the same work for each column ?
how ca be the line : << df_small = df_small.set_index(['a','b','c','d'])['e'] >>>

Comment: @dimzev - Can you change data sample from my answer and add expected ouput to question? Not understand from comment what need.

Comment: i add data to my first post for you see it. I am very sorry for my poor English ...!!